# Size and height of binary tree, different interpretations?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, binary-trees

I can't seem to get my head around the formulas to use for size of binary tree. Depending on who I ask, what website, etc. 
I see different similar answers.

So if someone could explain simply either: the differences between these formulas, the cases to use one or another, or any other explanation. It would be greatly appreciated.

**I've seen:**

- 2^h
- 2^(h+1)
- 2^(h+1) - 1

**And I've seen the reverse for calculating the height:**

- log(n)
- log(n+1)
- log(n+1) - 1

*assume base 2*

If someone could clear up my confusion that would be appreciated.
I'm an undergraduate at university, that needs to make sure my revision flashcards are correct! Thanks! :)

Comment: At this stage in your education, I recommend that you shift your focus away from trying to memorize formulas, and towards learning how to re-derive the formula whenever you need it.  Memorizing formulas isn't very useful for advancing your understanding.

Comment: I wasn’t so much concerned about memorising, more about why I’m seeing so many variants depending on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let us start with some definitions:

- the size of a binary tree $T$, often denoted $|T|$, is the number of nodes. I believe it is what you called $n$ in your post. The size of a binary tree can be computed by induction using:

  - the size of the empty tree is $0$;
  - the size of a node $N(l, r)$ is $1 + |l| + |r|$.
- the height of a binary tree $T$, denoted $h(T)$, can have two definitions that I know of. However, both have the same induction relation for a non-empty tree, which is $h(N(l, r)) = 1 + \max(h(l), h(r))$. The difference comes from the convention for the empty tree.

  - the first one defines the height as the maximum length of a path from the root to a leaf. As such, the height of the empty tree is defined (by convention for convenience purposes) as $-1$, and the height of a tree with one node is $0$;
  - the second one defines the height as the maximum number of nodes in a path from the root to a leaf. As such, the height of the empty tree is $0$, and the height of a tree with one node is $1$.

  I prefer to use the first definition, but this is a matter of personnal choice. After all, it only results in an offset of $1$.

Now for your formulas and reverse formulas, it is very unclear what you are trying to do. My guess is that you have seen some formulas that compare the height and the size of a binary tree. What can be proven is the following (using the first convention for height):

$$h(T) + 1 \leqslant |T| \leqslant 2^{h(T) + 1} - 1$$

The proof for this is a proof by induction using the previous induction relations for both the size and the height.

The previous inequalities can be tweaked a bit to obtain:

$$ \log_2 (|T| + 1) - 1 \leqslant h(T) \leqslant |T| - 1$$

However, note that even though those inequalities can be equalities in some cases, this is not always the case.

When using the second convention for height, those formulas would become:
$$h(T) \leqslant |T| \leqslant 2^{h(T)} - 1$$
and
$$ \log_2 (|T| + 1) \leqslant h(T) \leqslant |T|$$

However, when computing time complexities, like in AVL trees, only the asymptotics matter. For example, in AVL trees, $h(T) \in \mathcal{O}(\log |T|)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $h=1$, all three formulas give different sizes, so it suffices to build a tree of height $1$ and count the nodes. If no formula gives the correct answer, question the definitions of $h$ and $n$.

---

The formula for the height is obtained by inversion. $n=f(h)\iff h=f^{-1}(n)$.

Comment: I have no idea what your trying to say by this, apart from the fact an inverse should get you back to the same value. 
How does this answer the question?

Comment: @BradleyCable, this is describing a procedure you can follow to figure out the answer to your question yourself.  Have you tried building a tree of height 1, and counting the number of nodes?  How many nodes did you get?  Which formula gave the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define $h$ and $n$ first to use any of the formulas.

Consider $h$ starting from $0$, i.e. root is at height $0$.

$2^h$ gives the maximum number of nodes at given height $h$ and $2^{h+1}-1$ gives the maximum number of nodes in a complete binary tree of height $h$. And for the rest as you mentioned, take their inverses to get the height.